# Check Array if it contains a blocked file type in Outlook

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code that if the file type in the directory is blocked in outlook, it will not be included in the attachment.

```
Dim objMail as object
dim i,count as integer
With objMail
        .Subject = "sample"
        For i = 20 To lRow ' directories starts in row 20 in column O 
            On Error GoTo pst
            attach.add main.Range("O" & i).Value
pst:
        If count = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Some files is not allowed."
            count = 1 'count 1 so that this error will not be displayed again and again
        End If
        Next i
end with
```

This already works, but my problem is if the user adds another file type and the blank cell is between the non-blank cell, it will not be populated.

I have this code that adds the directories in column O and populate it.

```
dim file as variant
file = Application.GetOpenFilename("All Files, *.*", , "Select File", , True)
For i = 1 To UBound(file)

    lRow = Cells(Rows.count, 15).End(xlUp).Row
    lRow = lRow + 1
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main").Range("O" & lRow).Value = CStr(file(i))
Next i
```

Is there any other way to check first if the contents in the array is one of the blocked file type in outlook?

Can you give me a heads up on what to do, if i check the blank cell from `O20-29` and insert the directory in the first blank cell found or check the array? By the way these are the [blocked file types in Outlook](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Blocked-attachments-in-Outlook-3811cddc-17c3-4279-a30c-060ba0207372).Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim sFileType As String, Extn As String
    Dim MyAr As Variant, file As Variant

    '~~> List of blocked types
    sFileType = "ade|adp|app|asp|bas|bat|cer|chm|cmd|com|cpl|crt|csh|der|"
    sFileType = sFileType & "exe|fxp|gadget|hlp|hta|inf|ins|isp|its|js|jse|"
    sFileType = sFileType & "ksh|lnk|mad|maf|mag|mam|maq|mar|mas|mat|mau|mav|"
    sFileType = sFileType & "maw|mda|mdb|mde|mdt|mdw|mdz|msc|msh|msh1|msh2|"
    sFileType = sFileType & "mshxml|msh1xml|msh2xml|ade|adp|app|asp|bas|bat|cer|"
    sFileType = sFileType & "chm|cmd|com|cpl|crt|csh|der|exe|fxp|gadget|hlp|"
    sFileType = sFileType & "hta|msi|msp|mst|ops|pcd|pif|plg|prf|prg|pst|reg|"
    sFileType = sFileType & "scf|scr|sct|shb|shs|ps1|ps1xml|ps2|ps2xml|psc1|"
    sFileType = sFileType & "psc2|tmp|url|vb|vbe|vbs|vsmacros|vsw|ws|wsc|wsf|wsh|xnk"

    '~~> Create an array of blocked types
    MyAr = Split(sFileType, "|")

    file = Application.GetOpenFilename("All Files, *.*", , "Select File", , True)

    If file = False Then Exit Sub

    For i = 1 To UBound(file)
        '~~> Get file extension
        Extn = Right$(file(i), Len(file(i)) - InStrRev(file(i), "."))

        '~~> Check if Extn is a blocked type
        If IsInArray(Extn, MyAr) Then
            Debug.Print file(i) & " is of blocked type"
            '~~> Do what you want
        Else
            '~~> Do what you want
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    IsInArray = Application.Match(stringToBeFound, arr, 0)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The blocked types can be found here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Blocked-attachments-in-Outlook-3811cddc-17c3-4279-a30c-060ba0207372

If I were to do it, I would probably store this in a separate worksheet where I store static data for validation. For example, you can then read these types into a dictionary and use dictionary.exists method to test if any of the attachments you are looping through is one of the blocked type.

```
' to create a dictonary
dim objDic as object: set objDic = createobject("scripting.dictionary")
```

I personally don't prefer to use `MsgBox` in each loop since it breaks the code. You might want to store the error messages in a separate array and use join to output all the error messages at once just before the sub ends.

Comment: In which part of the script are you referring to? MsgBox doesn't matter to me, but thanks. Can you please give me some heads up on my main problem? Thanks!